# merging two strings to shape a file path

Tags: java, string, file

assuming that we have a folder with path:

```
path="C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\here"
```

also, consider a ***File[]*** named *readFrom* has different files. as an example, consider following path  which refering to a  file:

```
C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\files\\1\\sample.txt"
```

my question is, how can i have a string with following value:

```
String writeHere= "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\here\\files\\1\\sample.txt"
```

**EDIT**
I should have mentioned that this path is unknown, we need first to read a **file** and get its path then write it into another folder, so for the path of writing I need **writeHere** as input. in conclusion , the answer should contains the way to get the path from the file too.

Comment: Do you want to know how to manipulate strings?

Comment: @Joiner yea, but strings that belongs to a **File []** type

Comment: What does it mean "we need first to read a file and get its path"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String s1="C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\here";
String s2="C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\files\\1\\sample.txt";
String s3=s2.substring(s2.indexOf("\\files"));
System.out.println(s1+s3);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\here\files\1\sample.txt
```

---

To get `Absolute` Path of file

```
File f=new File("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\files\\1\\sample.txt");
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: perfect! I seen another solution on net whiich was too complicated. but yours so simple haha.

Comment: although your way is static and need to change **indexOf()** manually

Answer (score 0):

Split the into arrays and merge the `path` with split-ted string

```
String path="C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\here";
String [] splt = yourPath.split("\\");
finalPath = path + "\\" + splt[3] + "\\" + splt[4] + "\\" + splt[5];
```

**yourPath** is the path refering to a file

Changing the folder's path

```
File afile =new File("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\files\\1\\sample.txt");
afile.renameTo(new File(finalPath))
```

Comment: @user1064929 your path from files from example C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\files\\1\\sample.txt"

Comment: @user1064929 edditted

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the String and do not need to read the file, use string concatenation with is just str1 + str2.  If you need the File object create a base File object on the initial path and then two new File objects from that:

```
File path = new File("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\here");
String[] files = { "files\\1\\sample.txt", "files\\3\\this.avi" };
for (filename in files) {
  File f = new File(path, filename);
  ...
}
```

Oh, I think I see better what you want to do.  You want to "reparent" the files:

```
// Note: 
//   newParent I assume would be a parameter, not hardcoded
//   If so, there is no hardcoding of the platform specific path delimiter
//   the value, start, is also assumed to be a parameter
File newParent = new File("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\here");
File[] readFrom = ...;
for (File f in readFrom) {
    String[] parts = f.list();
    String[] needed = Arrays.copyOfRange(parts, start, parts.length);
    File newFile = new File(newParent);

    for (String part in needed) {
      newFile = new File(newFile, part);
    }
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you could do something like:

```
String name = "Rafael";    
String lastname = " Nunes";    
String fullname = name + lastname;
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/IdVI6m) you can see the string concatenation working, and you can often visit the Java documentation.

Comment: so pathetic! you downvoting all my posts!! haha

Comment: huh? I didn't even have reputation to do so.